# How to convert Uint8Array to Uint16Array or string

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser

How to revert from step 3 to step 1?
I read a lot and used google before asking.
Here is my listing with comments:

```
// --- STEP 1 ---
x1=getFile('filename');
// I get raw 16 bit binary string (it is not just a text)

// --- STEP 2 ---
x2=x1.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});
// I convert string to array with ASCII codes (some of them are above 255)
// first four elements of this array: 63367 63457 95 22

// --- STEP 3 ---
x3=new Uint8Array(x2);
// I convert ASCII codes to 8 bit data array
// first four elements of this array: 135 225 95 22

// --- STEP 4 (PROBLEM) ---
// - OPTION A (WORKING) -
// if I save x4 to binary file, and then read it (like in STEP 1)
// then data is the same as in original
// this means that load file 1, do STEP 2, do STEP 3, save as file 2,
// load file 2 will result in file 1 has exactly the same 
// bytes as file 2 (compared in Total Commander)
// - OPTION B (PROBLEM) -
// problem is how to convert this Uint8Array (from STEP 3)
// back to 16 bit ASCII codes array (like STEP 2),
// or just to correct JavaScript string
// (like it was in STEP 1 before you started to convert it to arrays)
// to make this question more simple:
// how to revert from step 3 to step 1
```